# Rspec GET to a different endpoint for a second - ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-grape

In my Grape/Rails app I've implement maintenance mode in `ApplicationController` so when this mode is active it will redirect to the `maintenance_mode_path` from anywhere in the app. How to force rspec to be in a different endpoint for a while eg. `api/v1/new_endpoint` while the whole test takes place in the `MaintenanceModeController` ?

`maintenance_mode_controller_spec`

```
context 'when maintenance mode is active' do

  context 'when current page is not maintenance page' do
    let(:call_endpoint) { get('/api/v1/new_endpoint') }

    it 'redirect to the maintenance page' do
      call_endpoint
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:redirect)
    end
  end
end
```

But with code above I've got an error

> Failure/Error: let(:call_endpoint) { get('/api/v1/bank_partners') }
>
> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/api/v1/new_endpoint", :controller=>"maintenance_mode"}

Answer (score 2):

You can't really test this at all with a controller spec. Controller specs create a instance of a controller with a mocked request which you then run tests on. When you call for example `get :show` in a controller test you are actually calling the `#show` method on your mocked controller.
Since it does not actually create a HTTP request so there is no way for it to actually interact with the other controllers in the system.

Use a [request spec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) instead:

```
# /spec/requests/maintainence_mode_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Maintenance mode", type: :request do
  context 'when maintenance mode is active' do
    context 'when current page is not maintenance page' do
      let(:call_endpoint) { get('/api/v1/new_endpoint') }
      it 'redirects to the maintenance page' do
        call_endpoint
        expect(response).to redirect_to('/somewhere')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

> Request specs provide a high-level alternative to controller specs. In
>   fact, as of RSpec 3.5, both the Rails and RSpec teams discourage
>   directly testing controllers in favor of functional tests like request
>   specs.